# How to find a sub-element by xpath inside a WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a login form (with the two canonical user and password fields) in a web page with python and Selenium (the page is general so I cannot use the id of the field or the xpath in the specific site).

To do so in a general way I get all the form in the webpage with

```
for form in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//form'):
```

and than I want to find all the input fields with

```
for input_field in form.find_elemenents_by_xpath('.//input'):
```

but I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_elemenent_by_xpath'
```

Online I've found that I can use "find_element" on a webElement, but it not works.

Someone can help me? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code

You entered `elemenents` instead of `elements`